# Prime number decidability: recursion theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, recursion, turing-machines, decidability

I have a problem with this task:

Is there a Turing machine $M$ able to write the following language, where a $\langle M \rangle$ is the usual encoding of the machine $M$?

The language is: $L = \{ w \in \{0,1 \}^* |    1 \langle M \rangle w ; \text{is a prime number}\}$ .

Can we use recursion theorem to prove this, please? Or do you have idea how to proceed?

Comment: Just a point of order: it's nice that you know HTML, but to directly put HTML tags in your question is a waste of time for you and a mild annoyance for everyone else.